# Have others explored Mendelson's approach to comprehension?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic

Mendelson, in *Introduction to Mathematical Logic*, 4th ed, 1997, had a more elegant approach to comprehension than predecessors, in my opinion.

With  $x\in\mathbf{V}$ short for $\exists y(x\in y)$, and $\alpha$ any formula in the language of set theory (possibly without =), use the axiom schemas:

SE: $\exists y(y=\{x|\alpha\})$ and CA: $\forall x(x\in\{x|\alpha\}\leftrightarrow x\in \mathbf{V}\wedge \alpha)$

A class is a set just if it is a member of $\mathbf{V}$. Mendelson goes on and develops NBG set theory on the basis of these, and further assumptions.

*Question:* Have others explored other set theories, with an approach as this?

Comment: Could you explain? Your presentation of SE looks like general comprehension, which is immediately refuted by the Russell argument, with $\alpha=$ $x\notin x$. But you have unbalanced parentheses, and so I fear I may have misunderstood.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins The "$\in{\bf V}$" part of CA gets around this unless I'm missing something: letting $\rho=\{x\vert x\not\in x\}$, we get from $\mathsf{CA}$ that $\rho\in \rho\leftrightarrow \rho\in {\bf V}\wedge\rho\not\in\rho$, which of course isn't a contradiction.

Comment: Note that any theory $T$ whatsoever has an accompanying extension $\hat{T}$, which is to $T$ as $\mathsf{NBG}$ is to $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Roughly, a model of $\hat{T}$ is a pair $(M,S)$ where $M\models T$ and $S$ is a collection of subsets of $M$ which satisfy the obvious comprehension scheme. As with $\mathsf{NBG}$ this can be phrased in a couple different ways (e.g. two-sorted or not), and for each $M\models T$ the structure $(M,\mathcal{P}_{def}(M))$ is the minimal model of $\hat{T}$ with first-order part $M$. Really, this is just **second-order logic with Henkin semantics** built on top of $T$.

Comment: I won't be able to sleep because of the mistmatched parenthesis.

Comment: What is "LAST"?

Comment: @NoahSchweber If you are right, then this is just the ordinary one-sorted treatment of GBC, which goes back to von Neumann. I object to the one-sort treatment, since there is actually little parallelism of sets with classes, and so I find the two-sorted treatments are far more clear. But they are bi-interpretable, so basically the same. What is the question here, then?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Oh I agree that this seems to just be the one-sorted approach to NBG (and I'm not saying I like the set-up).

Comment: @AsafKaragila "Language of axiomatic set theory" I think - I've seen this abbreviation in some old textbooks.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Yes, there was an unbalanced parenthesis. I edited.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins The question was whether other set theories, as non-wellfounded ones, have been explored with an approach to comprehension as the one pointed to.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Your second comment seems to answer the question (more than completely).

Comment: @AndreasBlass I understand that point of view. However, one might find that other theories support other, or supplementing, points of view.

Comment: For example, it may be that a set theory reasonably permissive with $\alpha$, in SE and CA,  will neither support a (global) foundation principle nor a (global) extensionality principle.

Comment: is $\mathbf{V}$ a primitive constant? IF not, then how it is exactly formally defined?

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar $x\in\mathbf{V}$ is short for $\exists y(x\in y)$. So it was imprecise of me to state that $\mathbf{V}$ was "taken as a universal class"; I'll edit.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, in your comment you said "since there is actually little parallelism of sets with classes," What do you mean by that??? It appears to me that sets are just special kind of classes, i.e. subspecies of classes, namely those that are elements of other classes, truely classes can be proper while sets cannot, yet that's not a big difference, both sets and classes have members, and both can extend predicates, and that's more intimately related to their essence. I find little parallism between finite and infinite sets, should that call for a two-sorted treatment for them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! There are other set theories explored along this way generally speaking.

(1) Quine's Mathematical Logic $\sf ML$ adopted a similar approach on top of his $\sf NF$, and easily one can get a similar treatment on top of $\sf NFU$. See: Quine, Willard Van Orman (1951), Mathematical logic (Revised ed.), Cambridge, Mass.: Harvard University Press, ISBN 0-674-55451-5, MR 0045661

(2) Randall Holmes in his theory about symmetric extensions also used a similar approach. https://randall-holmes.github.io/Drafts/symmetryrevisited.pdf

I also used this approach in a closely related article on: https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.08299

(3) [Vopenka](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-alternative/#VopeAlteSetTheo)'s alternative set theory

(4) Holmes [Pocket](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/settheory-alternative/#PockSetTheo) set theory

Comment: Thank you for the reminder of (2-4)! I believe other interesting approaches may be explored, but, obviously, and also as evidenced from the comments, the class jargon may be modified. It may nonetheless be useful when thinking about many matters.